# Can't Send SQL Server Database Mail Through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a SQL Server procedure that does inserts and sends an e-mail to a recipient.  The procedure works as expected inside of SSMS.  When I call the procedure using the mssql wrapper in PHP

```
mssql_query("EXEC myprocedure 'mypara1' 'mypara2'");
```

the inserts are performed, but the database mail function is not performed.  I stripped out the insert from the original procedure and left the database mail function in the procedure by itself and no e-mail was sent.

Is there a reason why database mail is disabled if you use the 'mssql_query' function?  Is there another way for me to call my procedure so that database mail functions as expected?

Comment: are you using the same login when you're testing this? whatever user php is logging in as may not have the same right as whatever you logged in to ssms as.

Comment: you're calling a stored procedure which is black boxed to your server language.  Meaning, that if in fact SSMS is able to execute your stored procedure & send the mail with the same exact parameters, then php should be able to to, since you say it's doing something like inserting rows.  You can take a look at what's going on either on the exchange server (or similar) via it's tools log analyzer, or if you have sql 2005/08, it has a mail queue table for you to look at.  Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187540%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @MarcB It was indeed an user access issue.  Feel free to put this down as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the same login when you're testing this? Whatever user php is logging in as may not have the same rights as whatever you logged in to SSMS as.